# Php in_array / strpos does not work - How to find an 'exact' match?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

OK..

I'm working blind on a "big" product web app...

We've got a couple of thousand products each with a bunch of data elements coming in from multiple vendors in various formats... so, needless to say, we can't see the data...

Here's the short version of today's problem...

We want to extract the "size" from the 'product name'

```
$product_name = "Socket Assembly w/ 25 ft Lamp Cord - 14 Gauge ";
```

and here's "part of the Sizes array....

```
$lookForTheseSizes = array( ...'Gallon','gal','Gal','G','Gram','gram','g','gm','Gauge','gauge'... );
```

The Sizes array, currently with around 100 values,  is built dynamically and may change with new values added without notice.

So this script does not always work... as it is dependent on how the Sizes array values are ordered.

```
foreach ($lookForTheseSizes as $key => $value){
    if (strpos( $nameChunk,$value) !== false) { 

        echo 'match '.$nameChunk.' => '.$value.'<br/>';                 

        $size = $value; 
        break;
    }
}
```

For example... when $nameChunk = "Gauge"  ... the script returns a "match" on 'g' first....

So... my question is this...
Is there a way -regex or standard php 5.4 or better function- to do an extract find/match ...  WITHOUT first sorting the Sizes array ?

Comment: What prevents you from sorting the sizes array?

Comment: This may or may not be an 'extreme situation'.  I've got 8-10 vendors with 10K plus proudcts  and  each vendor has their own 'system' for names... I don't want to deal with all that... Cherry's answer below needs your up vote.. cause with the "iU" in his regex... that means the array is not a issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product_name = "Socket Assembly w/ 25 ft Lamp Cord - 14 Gauge ";

$lookForTheseSizes = array('Gallon', 'gal', 'Gal', 'G', 'Gram', 'gram', 'g',
                           'gm', 'Gauge', 'gauge', 'ft');
foreach($lookForTheseSizes as $unit)
{
    if (preg_match('/(?P<size>[\d.]+)\s*' . preg_quote($unit) . '\b/U', 
        $product_name, $matches))
       echo $matches['size'] . " " . $unit . "\n";
}
```

Result

```
14 Gauge
25 ft
```

Or..

```
$units = join('|' , array_map('preg_quote', $lookForTheseSizes));

if (preg_match_all('/(?P<size>[\d.]+)\s*(?P<unit>' . $units . ')\b/U',
             $product_name, $matches))
  var_dump($matches);
```

Look at `$matches` and do what you want.

```
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "25 ft"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "14 Gauge"
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "25"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "14"
  }
  ["unit"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "ft"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Gauge"
  }
```

I would throw out the case-sensitive repeating units from the array and use additional modifier `i` in regex (it will be `/iU` instead of `/U`).

Comment: Thanks Cheery...

I probably need to put you on the payroll... I'm not a "regex" guy.

+1 for "iU" ...

+1 for catching multiple occurances... 
this script is sitting inside a much bigger one and "conjective phrases' - "w/ 25 ft Lamp Cord" have already been extracted. 

So the $nameChunk is clean...   I just need to know if that "word" is a "size" or not... v. "4 Pack" 

There are other places where I need all of the size atributes.

One question... what if there is no "number"...  $product_name = " BioBizz Bio-Bloom Gallon " ?
How would your regex be modified to catch "gallon or Gallon".

Comment: @BillWarren use `(?P<size>[\d.]+)?` And `/U` modifier is not really needed here, but it does not affect the results.